# curl "Unsupported Media Type" error in IBM Speech

Tags: api, curl, audio, ibm-cloud, wav

I am currently using this command in terminal to try transcribe my [telephonic mono voice sample wav](http://www.voiptroubleshooter.com/open_speech/american.html%20http://www.voiptroubleshooter.com/open_speech/american/OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav) with 16 bps at 8 kHz sample rate, to the IBM Speech-to-Text engine.

```
curl -X POST \
-u "apikey goes here" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/wav", "model: en-US_NarrowbandModel" \
--data-binary @{path_url_goes_here)/OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

The output, however, states that input wav is unsupported:

```
 curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
{
   "code_description": "Unsupported Media Type", 
   "code": 415, 
   "error": "Unable to transcode from audio/wav, to one of: audio/x-float-array; rate=16000; channels=1, application/srgs, application/srgs+xml, application/jsgf, application/fsm, application/bnf"
}
```

According to [IBM supported audio format list](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/audio-formats.html#audio-formats), I have changed my model to "NarrowbandModel" to allow the minimum input sampling rate of 8 kHz as stated.

My question: 
Is there something wrong with my request or audio file?

Update: I have tried converting the .wav to the MP3 format at constant 8 and 48 kHz sampling rate. With the changes to "Content-Type: audio/mp3", also result in the same output as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the model=en-US_NarrowbandModel as parameter in the URL. Following curl command works for me for your wav file.

```
curl -X POST \
-u "apikey:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-H "Content-Type:audio/wav" \
--data-binary @OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_NarrowbandModel"

{
 "results": [
  {
     "alternatives": [
        {
           "confidence": 0.985, 
           "transcript": "the birch canoes slid on the smooth planks "
        }
     ], 
     "final": true
  },
```

Comment: It works like a charm! There's definitely a long road ahead for me to learn. Can't thank you enough.